Read Arabic pdf book using python
I am working on reading an Arabic book using python (the pdf is selectable it does not require any OCR (optical character recognition to extract text from images)) so I have used multiple libraries pdfplumber, pdfminer.six and flitz (PyMuPdf)) this is one of the code I have used:
import pdfplumber
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import arabic_reshaper
import re

def clean_text(text):
    # Remove NULL bytes and control characters
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1F\x7F]', '', text)
    return cleaned_text

def reshape_and_bidi_text(text):
    # Reshape Arabic text and apply bidi algorithm
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
    return bidi_text

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    text = ""
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            page_text = page.extract_text()
            if page_text:
                text += page_text + "\n"
    return text

def save_text_to_file(text, output_path):
    with open(output_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
        text_file.write(text)

def convert_pdf_to_text(pdf_path, output_path):
    # Extract text from the PDF using pdfplumber
    extracted_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)
    
    # Clean the extracted text
    cleaned_text = clean_text(extracted_text)
    
    # Reshape and apply bidi algorithm to the text
    reshaped_bidi_text = reshape_and_bidi_text(cleaned_text)
    
    # Save the cleaned and reshaped text to a text file
    save_text_to_file(reshaped_bidi_text, output_path)
    print(f"Text from {pdf_path} has been saved to {output_path}")

# Example usage
pdf_path = r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Book Printed\البوليميرات العالية الأداء.pdf'
text_output_path = r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\output.txt"

convert_pdf_to_text(pdf_path, text_output_path)

So when using these libraries always I obtain the following output with wrong encoding and I don't know what to use to fix is?
Note: attached above https://www.noor-book.com/%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%A1-pdf?next=72c6f38a363b368a7bd978a8449ea530 is the arabic book I try to read

You can try Spire.PDF for Python.
pip install Spire.Pdf

Here is the code for extracting text from a PDF:
from spire.pdf.common import *
from spire.pdf import *

def extract_text_from_pdf(file_path, output_file):
    # Load a PDF document
    doc = PdfDocument()
    doc.LoadFromFile(file_path)

    extracted_text = []

    # Iterate over the pages of the document
    for i in range(doc.Pages.Count):
        page = doc.Pages.get_Item(i)
        # Extract the text from the page
        textExtractor = PdfTextExtractor(page)
        option = PdfTextExtractOptions()        
        text = textExtractor.ExtractText(option)
        extracted_text.append(text)

    # Save the extracted text to a text file
    with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
        text_file.write("\n".join(extracted_text))

    doc.Close()

file_path = "Arabic.pdf"
output_file = "ExtractedText.txt"
extract_text_from_pdf(file_path, output_file)

Here is the input pdf:

Here is the result:

It looks like the result is ok. But I am not familiar with Arabic, you can check the accuracy by yourself.
Note: I work for the company that developed this module.

Hello Mr. Malik thank you so much for your reply do I need to go the website to install spire.pdf or I can dowload it directly using the cmd ? Although I tried to run the cmd command and the code you provided but still I got weird symbols for the paragraph you provided can you provide more details on how did you obtain the output in the picture above?

@Hello I installed the module and ran the code in VS code. Regarding how to install the module, check this out: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Python/Spire.PDF-for-Python/Getting-Started/How-to-Install-Spire.PDF-for-Python-in-VS-Code.html
